# capturing a js var in php

Tags: javascript, php, post

Whats the best method of capturing a javascript variable sent using POST to a php file ?

My line of code that posts the variable is given below

```
 xmlHttp.open("GET", "testAJAX.php?$phpvariable="+$jsvariable, true);
```

Cheers

Comment: In the PHP script, write `$_GET['parameter']` to the file. What's the problem?

Comment: I would personally recommend you to perform an ajax request. Moreover, you should use jQuery, it will ne way easier to perform ajax requests through jquery rather than pure JavaScript :). In any case if you setter everything correctly it should ne working. Just get the variable in the PHP script

Comment: @briosheje Have a second look at the question. Doesn't that code look like an Ajax request? If so, do you think that jQuery would make it so much easier that it justifies loading such a big library?

Comment: in this case what would go into the [] ?

Comment: @user3881476 in this case `$_GET['$phpvariable']` :)

Comment: @Barmar, Problem is the `$` in a HTTP param name.

Comment: I assumed he didn't mean that literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet the problem is you've confused yourself with the `$` sign.

Change:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "testAJAX.php?$phpvariable="+$jsvariable, true);
```

To:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "testAJAX.php?phpvariable="+jsvariable, true);
```

Why?

Because calling `$_GET['$phpvariable']` (single quotes) would give you the value of the parameter, whereas calling `$_GET["$phpvariable"]` (double quotes) would give you nothing!   The `$phpvariable` inside double quotes would be assumed to be a PHP variable rather than a parameter name, and it would attempt to use the contents of the PHP variable (which probably doesn't exist) as the parameter name. (A parameter sent over HTTP is *not* a PHP variable.)

But if you don't include that `$` in your request parameter name, then both single and double quotes will work:  `$_GET['phpvariable']` or `$_GET["phpvariable"]`.

Also, Javascript variables don't begin with `$` (not normally, although they can): I almost didn't catch that mistake.

Comment: Javascript variables don't have to begin with `$`, but it's allowed, and a number of libraries use `$` as a variable, e.g. jQuery.

Comment: developerwjk - many thanks you were correct, and now it works! :)